# What is the default address of Solr Server (Solr 4.0) for use from a SolrJ client

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm trying to connect with Solr Server from a SolrJ client, but it gives an HTTPResponse Exception.

Here's my code:

```java
SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://"localhost":8983/solr/");
```

Here's the exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/NoHttpResponseException:

Does Solr have a default address? Where can you find it?

Comment: "localhost" has been quoted only in my question, but not the actual code.

Comment: How are you running Solr?

Comment: Over localhost on Tomcat - no config changes really. Everything's pretty default.

Comment: Solr does not have a default port but is just an web application.Is tomcat running on port 8983 ?? 8983 is the default jetty port. For Tomcat its 8080. Please check the configuration or the logs for the port.

Answer (score 11):

I am not familiar with SolrJ - but the endpoint seems to be missing the core name to me.

You would need to point your Solr client to a particular core.

The URI for the core would look like this (for reloading core command)

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/{{solrCoreName}}
```

The admin UI should be accessible at

```
http://localhost:8983/solr
```

Comment: yeah actually I've done that already. This is my actual address - http://"localhost":8983/solr/collection1/ - where collection1 is the core name

Comment: are you able to see the admin page coming up ok?

Comment: Yeah, the admin page shows up fine. I've to go to it through Tomcat admin at localhost:8080.

Comment: that's strange - is tomcat routing the traffic through port 8080? Can you try setting your client to point to `http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/` ?

Comment: I tried that earlier too and I just tried it again, just now. Same exception. 8080 is just for the admin console, not the client!

Comment: Actually turns out 8080 is for both, but its still not working

Answer (score 0):

By default, Solr will start on port `8983`. That can be changed though. You can change that for example in the `solr.in.sh` file using the `SOLR_PORT` property.