# Installed Solr: Shows Running, but seeing 404 on /solr

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, catalina

My versions:

```
CentOS 6.5 x86_64 kvm
Java 1.7.0_65
Solr 4.9.0
Tomcat6.0.24
```

I'm still learning on how to install Solr for my Drupal installation. Been following a few tutorials on getting this set up. Java and Tomcat work right now. I opened up the port 8080 on my iptables so :8080 loads the Tomcat page.

My current setup goes:

I grabbed what was in the `/example/solr` folder when I download Solr and unzipped this into a new folder called solr located here:

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF
```

I installed right here since a tutorial had me skip the step for placing the solr.xml file here to point to another location, like /opt/solr/ or whatnot:

So to further clarify, my file structure in here goes.

```
/solr/
  |--/bin/
  |--/collection1/
  |--/drupalsolr/   (this is my core/instace)
  |--/conf/
  |--solr.xml
  |--zoo.cfg
/solr.war
/weblogic.xml (was in here originally)
```

When I visit :8080 and then click to the Tomcat Manager, I see /solr is 'running'. Yet when I click /solr on here. It gives me a 404 error.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /solr/

type Status report

message /solr/

description The requested resource (/solr/) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.24
```

Where do I begin with fixing this? Is there any sort of errors I can find besides a 404 not found error?

---

### Update:

Ok, I am following this tutorial with how they used a Context Path file and have the Solr installation outside the Tomcat folder. I moved it to /opt/solr instead and edited the generated context path web.xml file that is located here: `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/web.xml`

Here is what I edited in the web.xml file now:

`<env-entry>
       <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
       <env-entry-value>/opt/solr</env-entry-value>
       <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    </env-entry>`

I now get the error 'FAIL: Application at context path /solr could not be started'. So I guess this means my actual Solr core isn't set up properly. I googled around and it might be my .jar files. It's hard to tell without a proper error.

I also made sure my $JAVA_HOME is set to `/urs/local/jdk`

Here are the errors form the log:

```
Aug 07, 2014 3:31:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Aug 07, 2014 3:31:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive solr.war
Aug 07, 2014 3:31:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Aug 07, 2014 3:31:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/solr] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 07, 2014 3:31:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory sample
Aug 07, 2014 3:31:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Aug 07, 2014 3:31:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Aug 07, 2014 3:31:01 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 07, 2014 3:31:01 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Aug 07, 2014 3:31:01 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/15  config=null
Aug 07, 2014 3:31:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 885 ms
Aug 07, 2014 3:37:14 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 07, 2014 3:37:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Aug 07, 2014 3:37:15 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default solr port is 8983 or is set in solr configuration and then as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16132346/438977) the URL structure is

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/{{solrCoreName}}
```

If this does not work it may be worth checking that solr service actually runs (for ubuntu / debian -> service solr 8983 status or similar for your distro or by checking process list).

Comment: No, doesn't work for that port. (8983) I see the error `FAIL: Application at context path /solr could not be started`. I went ahead and moved my Solr installed back into /opt/solr like I have it. I placed a .xml file into `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/web.xml` and this points to my Solr installation.

Comment: I updated my post with the edited contents of the web.xml file Tomcat6 created from my solr.war file.

Comment: Im going to go ahead and close this. Got to a new 503 error with the solr not wanting to initialize. Might be more with the Drupal module Im trying to get to run. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you're trying to integrate solr to drupal then you might want to check https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api and https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr modules.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Status 404 means that the requested resource does not exist.

We can read in [Tomcat 7 Per-Request Functionality](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/funcspecs/fs-default.html#Per-Request_Functionality), that:

> On each HTTP GET request processed by this servlet, the following
> processing shall be performed:
>
> - If the request is for a resource under `/META-INF` or `/WEB-INF`, return HTTP status 404 (not found).
> - If the requested **resource does not exist**, return *HTTP status 404* (not found).
> - If the requested **resource is not a directory**, but the resource path ends in `/` or `\`, return *HTTP status 404* (not found).
> - If the requested resource is a directory: **If directory listings are suppressed**, return *HTTP status 404* (not found).
>
> Requests for resources that **do not exist in the web application** (folder) must return HTTP status 404 (not found).

If you checked above and your app exists and the error is still there, check the followings:

- WAR file is deployed (e.g. `solr.war`) in `webapps/` folder which should be indicated by the following log entry:

  > INFO: Deploying web application archive solr.war
- Check logs, e.g.:

  ```
    cd /var/log/tomcat? && tail -f *.log *.txt *.out
  ```

  then hit the page again.
- Check if the app is up and running in *Tomcat Web Application Manager* (at `/manager/html`). Re-load just in case.
- Check the file permissions if Tomcat has access to its files, e.g.:

  ```
    sudo chown -R tomcat7 /var/lib/tomcat7/
  ```
- Check/rename/remove `.properties` files in `solr/WEB-INF` (just in case).
- Restart your Tomcat service just in case (each time when you change anything).
- Double check if the same problem happening on local server (e.g. using `links`).
- Check if `web.xml` is present inside `WEB-INF/` folder of your app, if not, follow the next point.
- Rename/delete corresponding folders for WAR files (e.g. `solr/` for `solr.war`), so they can be re-created upon Tomcat restart (make a backup if you modified anything there). Or simply re-deploy WAR files from scratch.

Troubleshooting/debugging:

- Increase level of Tomcat logger (`logging.properties`) to `FINEST` and re-check the logs again.
- Use `strace` to debug Tomcat (at the time when you hit the page), for example:

  ```
    sudo strace -fe file -p 1234
  ```

  where `1234` is PID of your Tomcat process (check via: `ps wuax | grep tomcat`). Instead of `file`, you can also use `network`, `write`, etc.